# PDO get result based on specific date from unix timestamp database

Tags: php, mysql

I have trouble getting this done. Been going through a few post here but couldn't understand what is going on as I am not good in php and mysql or pdo.

What I am trying to do is :

1) I want to get the number of counts based on a specific date, e.g : 24-01-2017
2) But my database unfortunately is using UNIX timestamp which I have to convert
3) Can the above 2 requirements be written in 1 sql statement?

Currently my code is like this :

```
$sqllastplay = "SELECT DISTINCT FROM_UNIXTIME(user_lastplayed,'%D, %M, %Y') AS day, count(*) as numberOfVisits FROM users GROUP BY day ORDER BY user_lastplayed";
  $querylastplay = $db->prepare( $sqllastplay );
  $querylastplay->execute();
  $lastplay = $querylastplay->fetchColumn();

<p><label>Last Play Date: </label><strong><?php echo $lastplay ?></strong></p>
```

I do not know how to continue anymore.

Hope you guys can help me out on this.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Remove `DISTINCT` and you might already be good, You're already Grouping based on day so distinct is not needed and might be messing up your results

Comment: fetchColumn() is unsuitable here as well

Comment: Hi Hanky Panky, so what do I need to change in order to put in a specific date that I want?

Hi Your Common Sense, do I change to rowCount() instead?

Comment: NO you have to change to the method which is appropriate here

Comment: I have a feeling that he needs something different, just a number without  group by. But as he is unable to tell what he wants, it's impossible to tell for sure.

Comment: Hi, Your Common Sense, maybe you are right. My database now is stored using UNIX timestamp. But I want to retrieve the number of records that I have in the database that are today's date or any other dates for example. But I do not know how should I code my statement. Hope this helps to clarify. =x

Answer (score 0):

You have written the query just a little change can result the output which you need.

```
"SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(user_lastplayed,'%D, %M, %Y') AS day, count(*) as numberOfVisits FROM users GROUP BY user_lastplayed ORDER BY day";
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok nevermind, I think I just got another way round it.

Thanks for the help!

And thanks for the one who down voted my questions too, you are so helpful.

```
$start_lastplay = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 20, 2017);
  $end_lastplay = mktime(23, 59, 59, 1, 20, 2017);
  $lastplay = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_lastplayed BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date";
  $lastplayquery = $db->prepare( $lastplay );
  $lastplayquery->bindParam(':start_date', $start_lastplay, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $lastplayquery->bindParam(':end_date', $end_lastplay, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $lastplayquery->execute();
  $lastplay = $lastplayquery->rowCount();
```